# Wikidata federated SPARQL query and variable

Tags: variables, sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service, federated-queries

In Wikidata (https://query.wikidata.org/), I tried the following simple SPARQL federated query with `SERVICE`.

I got the results back, but they do not seem to be what I expected. It seems that `?geonamesid` (i.e. reference to the entity "London") is not passed to `SERVICE` part, so that inside the `SERVICE` it is considered as a random variable and the results (`?Proxy`, `?Aggregation`, `?CHO` etc) are not related to London.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX ore: <http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX edm: <http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/edm/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  wd:Q21 wdt:P36 ?capital .
  ?capital wdtn:P1566 ?geonamesid .

   SERVICE <http://sparql.europeana.eu/>{
   SELECT *
   WHERE{                          
   ?Place owl:sameAs ?geonamesid .
   ?Proxy dc:subject ?Place .
   ?Proxy ore:proxyIn ?Aggregation .
   ?Aggregation edm:aggregatedCHO ?CHO .
   }
   LIMIT 1000
  }  
}
```

I tried the query separately at two SPARQL endpoints. This seems to be working. The following query was successful at https://query.wikidata.org and http://sparql.europeana.eu/ respectively (`PREFIX` omitted for readability).

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  wd:Q21 wdt:P36 ?capital .
  ?capital wdtn:P1566 ?geonamesid .
}
```

```
Select *
Where{
   ?Place owl:sameAs <http://sws.geonames.org/2643743> .
   ?Proxy dc:subject ?Place .
   ?Proxy ore:proxyIn ?Aggregation .
   ?Aggregation edm:aggregatedCHO ?CHO .
   }
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: `SERVICE` clause is evaluated separately from the other query and then joined locally. So, values are not pushed to the remote service. Docs: https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/FederatedQuery

Comment: https://w.wiki/9SJ?

Answer (score -1):

I replaced wdtn by wdt in your query. It works.

Demo : http://linkedwiki.com/query/Wikidata_federated_SPARQL_query_and_variable